# Batching DOM updates from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am wondering if there is a way to batch the actual dom writing when the contents of a directive is written to the DOM.

The use case is a large DOM where I want to optimize by updating the DOM in large batches rather than many small updates. I am trying to compile a list of dynamic child directives, but I don't see a way to ensure that the directives are packaged and sent as a single DOM update.

Consider the example bellow:

```
angular.module('test').directive('parentDirective',function($compile){

  return{
    link:function(scope, elem){
       var html = '';
       for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
         html += "<child-directive val='someValue'></child-directive>";
       }
       var e = angular.element(html);

       e.html(e);

       $compile(e)(scope);
    }

  };

});

//Using the parent-directive will dynamically add n child directives. 

<parent-directive>
<child-directive></child-directive>
<child-directive></child-directive>
..
<child-directive></child-directive>
</parent-directive>
```

Each child directive uses a template, and I am wondering, is there a way to "batch write" all the child directives in a single update? Rather than having each child directive issue a DOM update independently.
The child directives use isolate scope and the template is referencing the scope object throughout the template. The template is a large block of html referenced via a templateUrl in the child directive.

I can't skip the child directives by simply inlining the template since the structure needs to be repeated and data bound.